# Phonegap TouchEvent

Tags: android, cordova

My problem is that I want to play an audio/video file from the frontpage (index.html)

It's working like that:

```
function setaudio() {
$("#aud").prepend('<a href=# onclick=playaudio();><img src=icons/audio_file.png alt=Audiodatei width=90px height=90px></a>'); }
```

The function playing the audio:

```
function playaudio() {
window.plugins.videoPlayer.play(myaudio[0]);}
```

The problem it's not working on the index.html but it's working on linked sites f.e audio.html where I am calling setaudio(); again...

The catlog is telling me, also I am not clicking on the icon (at the index.html page) in an empty area of the screen:

```
03-01 13:19:23.980: V/webview(12235):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE
```

how to solve that? I am using the new Galaxy 10.1 - It was working with the same code on the Huawei MediaPad...also with Android 3.2

Comment: SOLVED -> the size of the HTML div was to small!

Comment: Was that really it? How small was your div at first, and how large is it now? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: I solved the problem like that, but it was maybe by chance, - I have a similar problem a "small" table entering rows - if I am having too much rows in the table (overflow -> scrollbar) the touch event isnt't working anymore and always get this singleCursor HandlerTouchEvent Error, can't find something on Google

Comment: Hmm, so maybe it happens when the element wants to use a scrollbar due to overflow but can't because telephones don't support it?

Comment: The situation was like: changed my device, also with a different os version 2.2 to 3.2 - changed the size of the div and it was working - now I am having a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722710/phonegap-touch-event-div-overflow - when an overflow in the div happens (adding rows) the links are not working anymore, - have to check scrollview or different ways visualizing my table

Comment: I really like to build custom code, but these kind of problems make me lean towards frameworks like jQuery Mobile and the like. At least, that's what I hope for: that they prevent those kind of problems :-)