# Phonegap button does not fire due to "singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport FASLE"

Tags: html, button, cordova, touch

A phonegap button does not fire in the newest Android 4.0.3. I get the debug message

```
"singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE"
```

(notice the wrongly spelled FALSE) after which the button does not fire or do anything. The button's code is

```
<div {{action someAction}}>click here</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517142/phonegap-touchevent) with the same message. It seems that was solved by resizing a div. I've gotten this same debug message, but it does not affect my event handlers. It also depends on the device/simulator that's being tested. For instance, this message is displayed on a Samsung Galaxy S2 running ICS 4.0.3, but does not show up in the emulator or a Nexus S 4G running the same Android version. Finally (for me) the message appears for any tap within the webview screen. Therefore it would indicate this is simply a debug message tied to the webview activity and not a problem with phonegap.

Do you have event handlers for the buttons or are they simply href links? I'm assuming the {{action someAction}} would be some sort of handler like onclick="functionName()". Try attaching an event handler to any of the buttons. Using normal js syntax:

```
document.getElementById('ButtonID').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
     alert('clicked');
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting... I'll have a go with try to resize the DIV and otherwise I'll try the other way around. With regard to whether it is Phonegap or the webview: the debug message is only generated if the click is not passed to phonegap. So yes, the webview does not pass the click, but that might be due to Phonegap setting some 'weird' event listener... I'll look into it if I have time, and accept your answer in the meanwhile!