# m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not issue

Tags: android, android-webview

In my application I have loaded MVC pages in android webview. MVC page has two text editor for username and password. While focusing on the Textbox, I am getting the warning: `m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not` .

Why I am getting this warning?

**Note**: I am getting this error after upgrading the android from **2.1** to **2.3.6**

**log:**

```
08-21 12:10:21.269: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:21.669: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:21.699: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:21.709: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.169: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.199: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.209: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.239: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.259: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.739: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.769: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.939: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:22.959: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:23.429: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:23.459: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:23.479: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:23.799: V/webview(2928):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
08-21 12:10:23.929: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:23.949: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:24.149: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:24.239: V/webview(2928): OnSizeChanged: Enter 
08-21 12:10:24.269: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:24.319: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:24.339: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:24.469: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:24.479: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:26.969: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:26.989: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:27.139: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:27.299: V/webview(2928):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
08-21 12:10:27.319: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:27.349: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:27.379: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-21 12:10:27.539: D/CONTEXT(2928): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not
```

Comment: Got any ideas ???? in my phonegap application also it is coming like this...

Comment: @Firnaz: No Firnaz, if getting let you know.

Comment: @Ponmala did you guys find a solution to that? I have thousands of logs like that

Comment: @jidma: no jidma, keep on searching....

Comment: Can you please add your code where you load the page into the WebView?

Comment: @Nicholas: just you load any webpage with input type text and try to enter anything, you can reproduce it

Comment: Found a related error discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398914/phonegap-button-does-not-fire-due-to-singlecursorhandlertouchevent-geteditable

Comment: I have no experience with this specific problem, but I see the word "FASLE" in this output and that looks like a red flag

Comment: Check if this happens on emulator. It may be device specific problem.

Comment: This looks like it's not a warning, just a `Log` at the `debug` level that may be in some library you are using, and maybe they forgot to suppress it.

Comment: @AndrzejDuś: Please check Note, i have mentioned when i am facing the issue

Comment: @StevenByle: This is warning only not a log output

Comment: The `D` in `D/CONTEXT(2928)` means debug, not warn. If it was a warning you would see `W`. Please read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html.

Comment: @StevenByle: Oh i was not aware of this. Thank you

Comment: @Ponmalar can this be closed?

Comment: @Josh: Every day i'm searching for the solution

Comment: Even though it's not something to worry about, it does causes performance issues (at least in my app). The WebView is literally spamming the log messages, causing the page to load very (read VERY) slowly. I've got several devices ranging from 2.1 to 4.3, where all of them load the page fairly quick. The device in question is a Samsung GIO (2.3.6), which spams the logs till hell freezes. Hence, the same WebView that loads the pages with Sonic-speed on the other devices becomes dreadfully slow on the Samsung. Isn't there some way to circumvent the holy spamming of logs?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a warning nor an error, just a debug message shown every time drawContentComposition is called. I imagine it shows that the value of hasComposition is false.

You can't do anything to avoid it so it shouldn't bother you... well, obviously, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You get this message to your log because of underlying WebKit logic - there should be some member function which check if there is any composition in main frame and post it's result to log, that is it. You should not worry about it.