# android WebView - content not editable

Tags: android, android-webview

I use a `WebView` to authorize a user on a social network using their API.

My `WebView` loads a form with 2 `EditTexts`(or whatever they're called in web development) and a button.

The strange issue: the keyboard does not show up when clicking on an `EditText` in the form BUT if the activity gets paused and resumed (for example I press HOME and then come back) the `EditTexts` become editable and I'm able to enter login data.

LogCat output for complete procedure (opening page, pausing activity and coming back) goes below. Yeah, I also noticed the wrong spelled "false". Any ideas?

```
 02-24 18:33:16.310: V/webview(19204):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
 02-24 18:33:16.715: V/webview(19204): doShortPress : mNativeClass - 1407128 mPreventDefault -  0
 02-24 18:33:16.810: D/dalvikvm(19204): GC_CONCURRENT freed 299K, 48% free 3037K/5831K, external 604K/1033K, paused 7ms+4ms
 02-24 18:33:16.830: D/navcache(19204): cursorInputFieldAction cursor=39c108, cursorFrame=1a7928
02-24 18:33:16.830: D/navcache(19204): CachedFrame::previousInputField this=1a7928, start=39c108, begin=39c040 end=39c3c4
02-24 18:33:16.830: D/navcache(19204): CachedFrame::nextInputField this=1a7928, start=39c108, begin=39c040 end=39c3c4
02-24 18:33:16.830: D/navcache(19204): cursorInputFieldAction next=39c16c, prev=0, action=4
02-24 18:33:17.095: V/webview(19204): OnSizeChanged: Enter
```

Comment: Try setting android:focusable=true for EditText's and also requestFocus

Comment: the thing is that the webpage I'm loading contains those EditTextes, I don't have access to them

Comment: @Pragnani sorry...I am confused...

Comment: but you got me to thinking the right way, I requested focus on my WebView and it solved the issue. Thanks dude, upvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found something in the Google group try this

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this really the answer? I am having the exact same issue but requestFocus does not help at all. I have only seen this problem on older (2.3.6 android versions)

Comment: Scratch that. I **does** work. This solves the problem. Actually, I find that all that is needed is the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` case.

Comment: I tried it in my project, but nothing changed. On Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.2.