# Android bug? WebView FASLE -> FALSE in LogCat

Tags: java, android, webview, touch

While working with WebView I get the following information in LogCat while touching the surface (scrolling webpage) inside of WebView.

```
06-12 16:59:03.385: V/webview(4168):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE
```

I am using only standard libraries, and for the WebViewClient I am using the following code.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

So as you can see I am not writing anything into LogCat.

My question is: **Is that a misspelled FALSE or maybe it has a different meaning?**

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054529/android-webview-content-not-editable)