# phonegap touch event / div overflow

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, touch-event

My problem:

I have a css div with a table (jquery-mobile 1.0), - If I add too much rows in the div (overflow) the touch event isnt't fireing the javascript functions...any idea?

it,s not fireing the functions and " overflow, before it's working fine !)

```
$('#mytable').append('<tr><td width=20%>
    <a href=add.html onclick=setId('+row.UserId+');>
    <img src=./icons/patientendaten.png width=48px height=48px></a></td>
    <td width=20%>'+row.Datum+'</td><td width=20%>'+row.Patient+'</td>
    <td width=20%><center><a href=# onclick=delete_entry('+row.UserId+');>
         <img src=./icons/delete.png></a></center></td><td width=20%><center>
         <img src=./icons/edit.png></center>
    </td></tr>');
```

More Details:

```
<div data-role="content">  

    <div id="twitter">

       <div class="ui-grid-d">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d">Akte</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d">Datum</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d">Patient/in</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-d"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d">Löschen</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-e"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d">Fallbeisp. erstellen</div></div>
        <br>

    <table id=mytable>

    </table>

  </div>
     </div>
         </div>
```

I am using jquery mobile 1.0 and the newest phonegap 1.7 on android 3.2

In addition the logcat gives me (when I am adding row nr. 6)

> 05-24 23:59:18.030: E/libEGL(16161): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
>
> 05-24 23:59:18.030: D/ShaderProgram(16161): couldn't load the vertex shader!

Here is my div:

[image: div-example]

Logcat:

```
05-23 17:05:51.800: V/webview(30492):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE
```

Comment: Which Javascript event isn't firing?  What code are you expecting to fire?

Comment: hi, added the code...hope the problem is clearer now !

Comment: Firstly, I think jquery would rather you attached the events in code rather than on the onClick attribute of the html tag, but I doubt that's your problem.  If you have any more detaisl about what the issue is that would help people.  Have you tried running with debugger on?

Comment: thx for your comment...maybe it's a scrolling problem in jqmobile?

Comment: would you suggest displaying the content in a different way? I thought a table in a div with adding rows is the easiest or common solution...

Comment: also tried it with lists and iscroll, same problem...

Comment: I came up with the solution that the blue div is the problem...jquery-mobile/phonegap have a problem with that overflow which leads to the error !

Comment: that's great.  Post your solution as an answer to your own question so others might be able to avoid the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the solution that the blue div is the problem...jquery-mobile/phonegap have a problem with that overflow which leads to the error !

```
05-24 23:59:18.030: E/libEGL(16161): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

05-24 23:59:18.030: D/ShaderProgram(16161): couldn't load the vertex shader!

#twitter {
    position:absolute;
    top:140px;
    left:40px;
    width: 880px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: #458d91;
    -moz-border-radius:16px;
    -khtml-border-radius:16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

If I am deleting the overflow and height, then there isn't any problem.

Using lists in that case is maybe a better way to go.

I also tried different jquery-mobile, jquery - in combination with different phonegap versions - this was tested on the samsung galaxy 10.1 tablet - android 3.2

Hope this helps.